# MS power automate read XML returns no children, can't get elemen value

Tags: xml, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I´m trying to read an XML file with Power Automate desktop app, however when reading it, only a single node is shown, and using "XML get element value" returns nothing.
No luck using xpath expressions either.

im trying to retrieve the "cnpj" value under
nfeproc/nfe/infnfe/emit/cnpj

i've removed sensitive info and shared the XML content as its originally formated by the provider

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00"><NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><infNFe Id="1231231231233841" versao="4.00"><ide><cUF>35</cUF><cNF>4333333333384</cNF><natOp>OUTRAS SAIDAS MERC OU PREST. SERV. NAO E</natOp><mod>55</mod><serie>1</serie><nNF>1231231231233841</nNF><dhEmi>2022-06-23T15:46:39-03:00</dhEmi><dhSaiEnt>2022-06-23T15:46:39-03:00</dhSaiEnt><tpNF>1</tpNF><idDest>1</idDest><cMunFG>1231231231233841</cMunFG><tpImp>1</tpImp><tpEmis>1</tpEmis><cDV>1</cDV><tpAmb>1</tpAmb><finNFe>1</finNFe><indFinal>1</indFinal><indPres>1</indPres><procEmi>0</procEmi><verProc>20.7.42.3</verProc></ide><emit><CNPJ>65465465487878</CNPJ><xNome>dummy text</xNome><xFant>Cdummy textQ</xFant><enderEmit><xLgr>dummy text</xLgr><nro>220</nro><xBairro>Ddummy textO</xBairro><cMun>35323232335</cMun><xMun>dummy text</xMun><UF>SP</UF><CEP>17dummy text6</CEP><cPais>1058</cPais><xPais>Bddddil</xPais><fone>123123</fone></enderEmit><IE>1321233</IE><IM>17733</IM><CNAE>12312313</CNAE><CRT>3</CRT></emit><dest><CNPJ>412312222231233</CNPJ><xNome>22dummy text</xNome><enderDest><xLgr>RUA dddddddd</xLgr><nro>6-9</nro><xBairro>VILA ddddddd</xBairro><cMun>3506003</cMun><xMun>ddrrreeee</xMun><UF>SP</UF><CEP>dd222222</CEP><cPais>1058</cPais><xPais>rrrrr</xPais><fone>123123123</fone></enderDest><indIEDest>1</indIEDest><IE>23232323</IE><email>ssssss@asdasdasd.com.br;ssssss@asdasd.com.br</email></dest><det nItem="1"><prod><cProd>sssss</cProd><cEAN>sssss</cEAN><xProd>sdsd sdsd TN-sdsd sdsd / RHB</xProd><NCM>84439933</NCM><CEST>2101800</CEST><CFOP>5949</CFOP><uCom>UN</uCom><qCom>2.0000</qCom><vUnCom>56.3200000000</vUnCom><vProd>112.64</vProd><cEANTrib>00165044</cEANTrib><uTrib>UN</uTrib><qTrib>2.0000</qTrib><vUnTrib>56.3200000000</vUnTrib><indTot>1</indTot><xPed>0</xPed><nItemPed>1</nItemPed></prod><imposto><vTotTrib>0.00</vTotTrib><ICMS><ICMS90><orig>0</orig><CST>90</CST><modBC>0</modBC><vBC>0.00</vBC><pICMS>0.00</pICMS><vICMS>0.00</vICMS><modBCST>3</modBCST><vBCST>0.00</vBCST><pICMSST>0.00</pICMSST><vICMSST>0.00</vICMSST></ICMS90></ICMS><PIS><PISOutr><CST>99</CST><qBCProd>0.0000</qBCProd><vAliqProd>0.0000</vAliqProd><vPIS>0.00</vPIS></PISOutr></PIS><COFINS><COFINSOutr><CST>99</CST><qBCProd>0.0000</qBCProd><vAliqProd>0.0000</vAliqProd><vCOFINS>0.00</vCOFINS></COFINSOutr></COFINS></imposto></det><total><ICMSTot><vBC>0.00</vBC><vICMS>0.00</vICMS><vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson><vFCP>0.00</vFCP><vBCST>0.00</vBCST><vST>0.00</vST><vFCPST>0.00</vFCPST><vFCPSTRet>0.00</vFCPSTRet><vProd>112.64</vProd><vFrete>0.00</vFrete><vSeg>0.00</vSeg><vDesc>0.00</vDesc><vII>0.00</vII><vIPI>0.00</vIPI><vIPIDevol>0.00</vIPIDevol><vPIS>0.00</vPIS><vCOFINS>0.00</vCOFINS><vOutro>0.00</vOutro><vNF>112.64</vNF><vTotTrib>0.00</vTotTrib></ICMSTot></total><transp><modFrete>0</modFrete><transporta/><vol><qVol>1</qVol><pesoL>0.550</pesoL><pesoB>0.600</pesoB></vol></transp><pag><detPag><indPag>0</indPag><tPag>90</tPag><vPag>0.00</vPag></detPag></pag><infAdic><infAdFisco>MATERIAIS P/ SUBSTITUICAO EM MAQUINAS E EQUIPAMENTOS LOCADOSDE NOSSA PROPRIEDADE, CONFORME CONTRATO DE LOCACAO.NAO INCIDENCIA DO ICMS CONFORME ARTIGO 7, INCISO IX DO RICMS/SP.</infAdFisco><infCpl>COMERCIAL) "</infCpl></infAdic><infRespTec><CNPJ>dedededed</CNPJ><xContato>MARQUES</xContato><email>ddd@ddddd.com.ddd</email><fone>dddd</fone></infRespTec></infNFe><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI="#444444444"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>BjMzgK2G/5YHRhdf7/Q+L0Jj1d4=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>IO9dMPPA0mIjZlZytE2UWvb6b1qTYgtiTNH+p1JqON8/chFAWOirckgumSg2hlvz/otDnxz5jihPg+Xy4jRvIkAhDGdlVF3ZMD0OoefOaZtekWLI1FL3MNKudCLt62K2otu6PPW0OnNYG6UCo9NkKCNPkZep7iqr0oAHUjFQAuq7FFcSBgMXSOyO4R/0sTeuDQtWNiWbxYf44ByXafTHZI0atvc+KqgtRUT8XyV6o4gAziiArPUwd8ry4MGclIzmL0G1jgQXwcSYwKNkyCxRend71dthVJ/j+YoTFfQRJJiPP1mC0MPucMofIzJDuryq/o4U3ywIUTT6YvLNSNxV2A==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></NFe>
    <protNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
        <infProt>
            <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
            <verAplic>SP_NFE_PL009_V4</verAplic>
            <chNFe>35220662771316000134550010000908471433470841</chNFe>
            <dhRecbto>2022-06-23T15:47:58-03:00</dhRecbto>
            <nProt>135220826254319</nProt>
            <digVal>BjMzgK2G/5YHRhdf7/Q+L0Jj1d4=</digVal>
            <cStat>100</cStat>
            <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
        </infProt>
    </protNFe></nfeProc>
```

[image: Read from XMl step]

[image: XML get element task]

[image: read xml result]

[image: get xml element error]

Comment: There's no XML at that link.  If you want us to help then you really need to fix that.  Just paste it in here as a code block.

Comment: Hello, Skin, I'm really sorry, I didn't realize the error in the link. I posted the XML as you suggested.

Comment: having sam eissue can you help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305125/get-value-from-http-response-xml-and-pass-it-as-a-field-in-next-http-request-fie